# Unable to create the home directory. This is most likely a permission problem

Tags: ubuntu, jenkins

I need to change `JENKINS_HOME` environment variable (`/var/lib/$NAME`) to `/home/someuser/someproject`.

I follow [instruction from here](http://blog.code4hire.com/2011/09/changing-the-jenkins-home-directory-on-ubuntu-take-2/) but get error:

> "Unable to create the home directory `‘/home/someuser/someproject’`. This is most likely a permission problem. To change the home directory, use JENKINS_HOME environment variable or set the JENKINS_HOME system property."

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins uses a service account to run its processes, that is why on the article the `JENKINS_HOME` is defined as below:

```
# jenkins home location
JENKINS_HOME=/home/jenkins
```

If you check this directory on your filesystem, the group and owner will be both `jenkins:jenkins`.

You need to change the ownership of your folder and give the folder to Jenkins group and user.

Example changing the ownership of the folder `someproject` to Jenkins:

```
cd /home/someuser/someproject
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins *
```

---

**Edit:** Since all the files and folder are owned by `jenkins`, it may be not possible to the service account to access the `someuser` directory, since only the logged user has permissions over it.

You will have to point to another directory (`/var` for example or even `/home/jenkins`) which could be accessed by Jenkins service.`

Comment: Have you tried just on `/home/jenkins` to see if it works?

Comment: Nothing happens

Comment: I was wrong: after `sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins *` all files in a new `/home/someuser/someproject` belongs to jenkins, but the problem is still the same...

Comment: Probably the Jenkins service account is not able to read the folder of the logged user, I have edited the question with this info, unfortunately I do not think it is possible to have the `JENKINS_HOME` inside a regular user folder

Comment: at this moment `someuser` is just a directory without special access. Is it possible to make dir structure like `/home/dir1/dir2/dir .../` or it should be just the very short root like `/dir` or maximum `/dir1/dir2` ?

Comment: Yes it may be possible, it is important to have the whole structure available for `jenkins` service account, you can test it and it may work as expected.